# How to resize .heic wallpaper for iPad?

Tags: macos, ipad, wallpaper

How can I resize one of the default *.heic* wallpapers from MacOS for my iPad?

I'm hoping to be able to resize the "Dynamic Big Sur Dark (Still)" wallpaper for my iPad (gen 8) Which has a scree size of 2160x1620px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've already downloaded the wallpaper to your Mac, you can access the .heic files downloaded from the following folder. I suggest using Terminal (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> then type 'Terminal'):

```
open /System/Library/Desktop Pictures
```

then, if you open the file to Preview (default app usually), from **Tools** > **Adjust Size**.

From here you can resize the file and save it as desired. You'd want to tap the drop-down and change it from inches to pixels and enter the dimensions you mentioned. If you need the dimensions to be "lopsided" from what they are original image, tap the little lock icon such that it appears unlocked and you'll have no issue entering your dimensions. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is your friend if you mess up.

[image: MacOS Preview Application Resize Image Panel]

Comment: You need quotes: `open '/System/Library/Desktop Pictures'`

Comment: I actually had quotes in my original statement, as it was pasted directly from my terminal then someone with higher rank suggested an edit to the post, and here we are 